# Scala Spark Add a Column with percentage of a number over sum

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset with schema

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- dist: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Say the dist is `[(A, 10), (B, 5), (C, 3)]`, and I want to add a column `[10/18, 5/18, 3/18]` which corresponds to the number divided by the sum.

How can I do that? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're starting with a Dataset of something like (updated to handle `Option[Map[String, Long]]`):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset

case class Model(id: Long, dist: Option[Map[String, Long]])

val ds: Dataset[Model] = List(
  Model(1, Some(Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 3))),
  Model(2, Some(Map("x" -> 100, "y" -> 50, "z" -> 30))),
  Model(3, None)
).toDS()
```

and your new column `percentage`, which will need to be a `String` column to display `{x}/{y}`:

### Spark >= 3.0.0

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{aggregate, col, format_string, lit, map_values, transform}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.LongType

ds
  // take just the values of the map `dist`
  .withColumn("values", map_values(col("dist")))
   // calculate the total per row
  .withColumn("total", aggregate(col("values"), lit(0).cast(LongType), (acc, x) => acc + x))
  // format column with total
  .withColumn("percentage", transform(col("values"), (c: Column) => format_string("%s/%s", c, col("total"))))
  .drop("total", "values")
  .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+---+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|id |dist                        |percentage               |
+---+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|1  |{a -> 10, b -> 5, c -> 3}   |[10/18, 5/18, 3/18]      |
|2  |{x -> 100, y -> 50, z -> 30}|[100/180, 50/180, 30/180]|
|3  |null                        |null                     |
+---+----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

which has a schema of:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- dist: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- percentage: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
```

---

### Spark < 3.0.0 (Tested using Spark 2.4.5)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, col, map_values}
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.aggregate._

val toDivisionUDF = udf(
  (values: Seq[String], total: Long) => 
    "[" + values.map(v =>  s"$v/$total").mkString(", ") + "]"
)

ds
  // take just the values of the map `dist`
  .withColumn("values", map_values(col("dist")))
   // calculate the total per row
  .withColumn("total", expr("aggregate(values, 0D, (acc, v) -> acc + v)"))
  // format column with total
  .withColumn("percentage", toDivisionUDF(col("values"), col("total")))
  .drop("total", "values")
  .show(false)
```

gives:

```
+---+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|id |dist                        |percentage               |
+---+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|1  |[a -> 10, b -> 5, c -> 3]   |[10/18, 5/18, 3/18]      |
|2  |[x -> 100, y -> 50, z -> 30]|[100/180, 50/180, 30/180]|
|3  |null                        |null                     |
+---+----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

which has a schema of:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- dist: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- percentage: string (nullable = true)
```

---

Note that the inclusion of `Option` hasn't changed the code at all as Spark handles Option, treating the field inside the Option as nullable.

Comment: I'm using Spark 2.4.3. Is there a way to do it without `aggregate` and `transform`?

Comment: @user17101610 I'll get back to you this evening on this.

Comment: Thanks! I can use `expr` to substitute `aggregate`, but so far I don't know how to work my way around `transform`. I tried to do `explode` and `collect_list`, but looks like I can't groupBy `dist` because it is a `map` structure

Comment: And by the way, is there a good way to handle `Option` in this case? `dist` can be `None`, and is `Option[Map[String, Long]]`

Comment: Updated! Had to use a `udf` for Spark 2 is all.

Comment: Interesting! Does this mean `udf` can handle `Option` automatically? I always thought I needed to do something like `option.get`.

Comment: Well in the above case the `udf` is no called directly on `dist` but on `values` which is created from the values taken out of the map. Nulls are handled here by the fact that `map_values(col("dist"))` will return null for a `None` instance of `dist`.